# SetWindowDisplayAffinity backcolor image/transparent

Tags: c#, winapi, user32

how to make transparent black square in SetWindowDisplayAffinity?
put a picture or transparent background instead of a black square

I need the window not to be visible at all in the video capture

Comment: `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` doesn't offer any sort of customization. If you need to capture the contents of a window obscured by another window, you're going to have to use a different screen capture approach. The [Windows.Graphics.Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture) namespace may work for you.

Comment: I need to hide the window when capturing the screen

Comment: That would be another alternative, depending on whether the window allows that. You could either hide it with a call to `ShowWindow`, [minimize it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31224092/1889329), or move it to the bottom of the Z-order.

Comment: it is visible to me but to those to whom I show no :)

Answer (score 2):

**I found a solution.**

```
const uint WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE = 0x00000011;
SetWindowDisplayAffinity (this.Handle, WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE);
```

I also used it. But it works in Windows 10 version 2004 and above. I tried on new versions of Windows and everything worked out, the window was completely invisible in the screen capture.