# Get the windows current display as images - C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to get the display of each open window beneath my app as an image,
I can't hide my app and then take screenshots because it's causing a flickering of the app.

Is it possible to get a stream of images from each window?

the app is c# winforms.

I tried to find a solution using WinAPI calls, but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for all the helpers

Comment: [Screen capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture). Alternatively you can use [`SetWindowDisplayAffinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) with the `WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE` flag (available starting with Windows 10 2004) on your application, and go ahead and use any of the screen capture solutions that capture the entire desktop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SetWindowDisplayAffinity backcolor image/transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70336544/1889329).

Comment: This is actually progress for me, I still need to check if I can filter other windows because   The window must belong to the current process. @IInspectable

Comment: The question doesn't ask how to hide other, foreign windows, though. If that is what you want, you should update the question with more detail.

Comment: @IInspectable Actually I asked for a stream of images of each open window, but like I said its a progress in other direction than I thought from the beginning. So thank you for your answer

Comment: *"can't hide my app"* - I took that to mean that you are the author of this program. Changing the display affinity should thus be possible. However, if you want a screen capture of all windows, even when they are partially occluded by other windows, you would have to look into [screen capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture).